# Visual Studio: C++\CLI wrapper assembly path dependency problems

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, c++-cli

Hey guys here is the scenario:

I have a small C# library project containing some device functions: DeviceLib.dll

To use this functions in C++ I created a wrapper project using CLI:  DeviceLibWrapper.dll

Finally I'm using a small C++ console app to test the wrapped stuff.
Everything is working as I expected.

To separate the dlls from the console app I createt a folder (c:\test_lib) containing all dlls needed and added the path to the systems "Path" variable.

I changed the configuration of the wrapper project to use the path variable and it works like a charm if the DeviceLibWrapper.dll is moved to the library folder.

If I try to move the C# library (DeviceLib.dll) to the folder I only get System.IO.FileNotFoundException (DeviceLib.dll assembly not found).

First I used a project reference to the C# lib in the wrapper project.

Then I tried the #using "DeviceLib.dll" directive and changed the "Resolve #using References" option using $(Path).
At least I added the C# dll as reference with full path.

But the result is still the same. 
If I copy the C# lib in the console output folder the application works otherwise it throws the assembly not found error.
So now I'm a little bit confused.

What is the best/recommended way to resolve such dependencies? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a [code base or probing path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location) in the app.config file.

Codebase:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
       <dependentAssembly>  
         <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"  
                           publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                           culture="en-us" />  
         <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"  
                   href="c:\test_lib\devicelib.dll"/>  
       </dependentAssembly>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Probing:

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="c:\test_lib"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

A good read on this subject is the documentation on how the runtime locates assemblies:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies